# Custom Validation in Model with Parameter from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

i have this chunk of codes in my controller

```
def create
  number = params[:number]
  @color = Colors.new(params[:colors])
  @color.save       
end
```

and i have this validation in model **color.rb**

```
validate :should_be_primary

def should_be_primary
   #validations here
end
```

I just want the validation should only run when my `params[:number] == 1`

Note: `params[:number]` is **only** a *parameter* and **not** a *table field*.

anyone please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def create
  number = params[:number]
  params[:colors][:param_number] = number
  @color = Colors.new(params[:colors])
  @color.save       
end

validate :should_be_primary
def param_number=(number)
 @number = number
end

def should_be_primary
   if @number
     #blah blah
   end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this on your **model.rb**

```
validate :should_be_pimary if self.number == 1

def should_be_primary
   #validations here
end
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that number is only a parameter from form

Comment: All I thought the **number** is a field of your table.